# Java calling a method and not waiting for response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, service

What is the best way to execute a method after a another method but not to wait for its execution:

Example I have an spring boot API:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{performanceCode}")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUserPerformance(@PathVariable String performanceCode) {
    return new ResponseEntity(userService.getUserPerformance(performanceCode), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

on the `userService.getUserPerformance(performanceCode)` I have to do

```
    @Transactional
    public UserDTO getUserPerformance(String performanceCode) {
      UserDTO  userDTO = // some logic..... ;

      //... some other code
  
      // here  I call this method that I don't have to wait for it to finish and also if it throws an error I shouldn't block the whole service to return error 
      userCalculationsService.resetUserPerformances(userDTO );
      return userDTO;
}
```

So my problem is that I want to call `userCalculationsService.resetUserPerformances(userDTO )` but  I don't want to wait for it till it finishes or  also if it throws an error inside the method I shouldn't block the whole service to return error.

Can someone help me on how to handle this?

Comment: You could use a `Thread` that runs this one method?

Comment: @Sorin can you provide me an example please

Answer (score 0):

In SpringBoot Application Main Class :

```
@EnableAsync
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {<packages......>})
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AurabotApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
  public Executor taskExecutor() {
    final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Thread-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
  }
```

In Controller you can call Async method as :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/invoke-command")
public class SlashCommandController extends BotClass {

  @Autowired
  AsyncService async;


  // To invoke Commands using SlashCommand
  @RequestMapping(value = "/{commandName}", method = RequestMethod.POST,
      consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
  public String runCommands(@RequestParam Map<String, String> request,
      @PathVariable String commandName) throws Exception {
    async.runCommands(request, commandName);
    
    return "HAHA";
  }

}
```

AsyncService Class :

```
@Service
public class AsyncService {


  // Asynchronous Service for SlashCommands
  @Async("taskExecutor")
  public void runCommands(Map<String, String> request, String commandName)
      throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException,
      FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException {
   //doSomething
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a small flow, which I used once to achieve the same objective.

Comment: Ignore the exceptions if not needed